# How does commutative property not hold for subtraction?

Tags: arithmetic

I don't get why commutative property is not valid under subtraction, because I find that it is
for example:
$5 - 3 = 2 = -3 + 5$ or rather $5 + (-3) = 2 = -3 + 5$
So how does it not hold true for negative numbers?

Comment: The example you wrote deals with commutativity for addition (of $5$ and $-3$). Why would subtraction be commutative? What sense does it make to ask "why" it is not? (whatever the sign of the numbers involved). That's life...

Comment: I changed the tag from commutative algebra to artihmetic because I don't think the "commutative algebra" tag is appropriate for this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explain to kid why subtraction is not commutative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755094/how-to-explain-to-kid-why-subtraction-is-not-commutative) or any of [those](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=subtraction+commutative)? Please next time use search engines (on this site and/or on the web) before (or instead of) asking.

Answer (score 3):

That is not the commutative property. If subtraction were commutative, what would mean that for any $a,b$;
$$a - b = b - a$$ and this is clearly not the case, for example take $a=1$ and $b=2$

Answer (score 2):

Addition is commutative:
$$a+b=b+a$$
This holds for any numbers $a,b$, e.g. $a=5$ and $b=-3$, as in your example.

Subtraction is not (always) commutative:
$$a-b\neq b-a$$
for most $a,b$ (not if $a=b$).

E.g. $5-3=2\neq-2=3-5$.